# Word document not reflecting change visually after vba code is used to indent a paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a simple vba code in Word 2010:

```
Sub IncreaseIndent()
    For Each p In Selection.Paragraphs
        p.LeftIndent = p.LeftIndent + InchesToPoints(0.25)
        p.FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.25)
    Next
End Sub
```

It works great, does what I need, and I have it associated to a shortcut key.  But I'm trying to figure out one last glitch it has.  When I use it, the paragraph indents, but it's not visually refreshed properly in the document.  I have to scroll so that the text goes out of view, and then scroll it back.  (Any action that makes Word re-render works, like switching to another program whose window is on top of Word, and back again.)  After that, the paragraph looks as it should.

[image: What it looks like when it indents, but does not re-render]

I'm thinking I'm missing some kind of p.Refresh / Re-render / Recalc command, but don't know what that is.  Anyone know how to cause the refresh in the vba code?

Thanks,
Sandra

Comment: just a shot in the dark but `Application.ScreenRefresh`?

Comment: David, you're brilliant, that was exactly it.  Please put in your answer so I can mark it as correct.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate what you describe, but there is a `.ScreenRefresh` method which might do the trick.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193095(v=office.15).aspx

Note: in the example code provided at MSDN (and as modified slightly, below), when I test it the toggling `ScreenUpdating` property has no effect, it *always* appears to update for me when I run it, even when set explicitly to `False`

```
Sub t()

Dim rngTemp As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)

rngTemp.InsertBefore "new"
Application.ScreenRefresh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```